# Is it possible to toggle these js tabs through the web console?

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering if it is possible!
i could not figure it out if it is possible, dont ask why i need it i just do. IT would be very helpful if you could tell me.

```
            var TabToggled = 0;
            function ToggleTab(value){
                if (value == 0){ // Toggle the register tab;
                    if (TabToggled == 1){
                        TabToggled = 0
                        $("#LoginForm_Landing").hide();
                        $("#RegistrationForm_Landing").show();
                        $(".RegisterTab").removeClass("RegisterTab_Deselected");
                        $(".LoginTab").removeClass("LoginTab_NowSelected");
                    }
                }else{
                    if (TabToggled == 0){
                        TabToggled = 1
                        $("#LoginForm_Landing").show();
                        $("#RegistrationForm_Landing").hide();
                        $(".RegisterTab").addClass("RegisterTab_Deselected");
                        $(".LoginTab").addClass("LoginTab_NowSelected");    
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: If `ToggleTab` is global function, then just `ToggleTab(1)`.

Comment: What i wanted to do is see if i could hide a tab for some easter egg hunters on my site! So i asked if i could use the console to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is just opening the JavaScript console on your browser and entering something like this `ToggleTab(0)` or `ToggleTab(1)`

Comment: Thank You I know js, but using the console isnt my skill set